# The use of colon in the sentence

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation, colons

I have a hard time understanding the use of the colon in the following sentence:

> Marriage is like a supermarket: easy to get into but hard to get out of.

Is the part after the colon a list of two elements or is it an independent clause where the part "It is" is omitted. For example:

> Marriage is like a supermarket: [it is] easy to get into but hard to get out of.

Comment: The latter. Some traditionalists would say that this use of a colon is unacceptable (I doubt even they would complain if you swapped it for a dash). However, I'd prefer the colon here as it introduces a reason for the preceding main clause. Colons tend to introduce fairly specific types of follow-on statements; dashes are more flexibly used.

Comment: Consider a similar sentence: *There was only man for the job: Peter.* I guess you could argue that *Peter* is an elided form of *it was Peter*, but I don't think it's necessary to say that an independent clause need follow the colon. Again, *We had the following for Christmas: turkey, beef  and cranberry pie.* I don't see how this can be considered an elision, since *the following* refers directly to the three foods; some such proposed clause as *they were turkey  beef and cranberry pie* doesn't work here.

Comment: @AlanCarmack Possible case for an Oxford comma, Alan? I've never heard of beef and cranberry pie, but I'm sure it's possible and might even be delicious;-)

Comment: Wait, since when is it "hard to get out of" a *supermarket*??

Comment: Yeah I'm with @ruakh on this one. Marriage is like a metaphor: very easy to break but hard to fix. Easier to just let it go and look for a better one.

Comment: @ruakh Two reasons I can think of: you're having too much fun filling up on all you want; you can't afford the checkout.

Comment: I agree with Alan.  You could possibly argue that "it is" is implied, but that's a stretch since there's no evidence of it and what follows a colon can be an independent clause but in no way is required to be.  (https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/colon.html - See "Emphasis.")

Answer (score 1):

A Colon separates two halves of a sentence when the second half is directly relating information about the first half.

Comment: The OP obviously realizes this generality. The question is about a specific sentence where that is *not* the case.

Answer (score -1):

Picking up [Edwin Ashworth](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/21655/edwin-ashworth)'s [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/353725/the-use-of-colon-in-the-sentence#comment820781_353725) and adding some references here some details:

A colon can have the function to lead from a statement on the left side to an explanation on the right side (see [grammarbook.com](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/colons.asp) *Rule 4*). In the sample text the sentence "**[It is] easy to get into but hard to get out of.**" is an *explanation* of the first sentence "**Marriage is like a supermarket.**"

To be fair, a colon can have the function to *introduce* a list of items (see [grammarbook.com](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/colons.asp) *Rule 1a*), but in the sample text the phrase "**easy to get into but hard to get out of**" is not a list of multiple items.